# Trouble getting wordpress working after moving servers

Tags: server

So I have 17 wordpress sites that I am moving from Server A to Server B.

All the sites have been up and running on Server A for over 2 years, no recent changes (ie, no new plugins, no new themes) to any of them.

I have moved all the files and all the databases to Server B. All good. 
Created MySQL users, gave permissions, all good.

Problem: Some sites work, some sites don't.

The sites that don't work are just a blank white page. Sometimes I can login to the admin, sometimes I can't.

Problem: Some sites have plugin errors (didn't exist before move)

The sites that don't work often have a bunch of PHP errors related to various plugins that prevents the site from loading.

The sites that work, work as if they were never moved.

Any ideas of whats going on?

Comment: Different versions of php?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include some additional information as well.  How did you move the files, ftp?  Did you compress them and then wget or something else?  What server software are you running?  Are the versions of everything the same, etc?  There really are a lot of things going on but as to my first comment, different php versions were my initial thought.

Comment: Files: Tar/Gzipped transferred by sFTP --- System: Ubuntu (saucy)  ----  Came from SmartOS (Solaris) -- I will go check what PHP version each system is running and report back.

Comment: Also the old server uses PHP 5.3.6 and the new server uses PHP 5.5.3 (should I downgrade for compatibility?)

Comment: Well, ideally you would update the software to work with 5.5.3.  However, WordPress' minimum requirement is 5.2.4 so most plugins correctly assume that's all they have to work with.  Php 5.5 introduced a lot of new things and deprecated a lot of stuff as well, which I imagine is what's happening here.  Give a recomplile to 5.3 a try a see how it looks after that.

Comment: @JonFurry was your issue ever resolved?